# Verneinung von mit dem Suffix "-gemäß" endenden Adjektiven

Tags: adjective, negation, compound-adjective

Ich würde gerne wissen, wie man ein Adjektiv verneint, das mit dem Suffix **gemäß** endet endet. z.B.

die Verneinung von **ordnung**s*gemäß* ist **un**ordent**lich**: Man leitet erstmal das Adjektiv aus dem Nomen ab und dann stellt das Präfix *un* voran.

Kann man man generel nach diesem Muster verneinen?

gilt unauftraglich als Verneinung von auftragsgemäß?

Vielen Dank im Voraus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die übliche und "normalste" Form der Verneinung von -gemäß-Wörtern ist mit *nicht*:

> nicht auftragsgemäß
>
> nicht ordnungsgemäß

Eine mögliche Verneinungsform, die jedoch sehr selten angewandt wird, sehe ich noch mit *-widrig*.

> ordnungsgemäß - ordnungswidrig
>
> auftragsgemäß - auftragswidrig
>
> anforderungsgemäß - anforderungswidrig
>
> sinngemäß - sinnwidrig
>
> gesetzesgemäß (auch: gesetzeskonform) - gesetzeswidrig / gesetzwidrig

(Achtung, *gesetzmäßig* ist etwas anders!)

Andere Formen der Verneinung, wie du sie vorschlägst, sind zwar möglich (vor allem im Reich der Poesie und der kreativen Sprachbastelei); sie sind im allgemeinen Geschäftsverkehr aber unüblich. Du würdest nicht ***unauftraglich*** sagen, ohne damit als Unikum, Schelm oder rettungsloser Bürokrat aufzufallen. Wenn du ***unauftragsgemäß*** sagst, fällst du weniger auf, aber ein leichtes Stutzen wirst du bei deinem Gesprächspartner vielleichct doch wahrnehmen. Das Wort ist regelgemäß (ha!) gebildet, aber es ist einfach nicht üblich. (Es ist ***ungebrauchsgemäß***, um diese Art der Wortneuschöpfung weiter zu strapazieren, oder **ungebräuchlich**, um eine etablierte Ausdrucksweise zu benützen.)

Es kann natürlich passieren, wenn du anfängst, solche Wörter regelmäßig zu verwenden, dass ihr Gebrauch sich  mit der Zeit durchsetzt.

**Sonderfälle**

Wie Kommentator Marzipanherz richtig bemerkte, gibt es noch

> unsachgemäß
>
> unzeitgemäß

als Negationen von *sachgemäß* und *zeitgemäß*. Diese beiden Fälle scheinen aber die einzigen zu sein, bei denen eine Negation von -gemäß-Wörtern mit un- sich eingebürgert hat.

Beobachtung dazu: Für mein Empfinden wirkt die Verneinung mit *un-* weniger aggressiv als eine Verneinung mit *-widrig*. Das ist eigentlich auch logisch erklärbar: *un-* drückt primär aus, dass die Eigenschaft nicht besteht (Fehlen einer Eigenschaft). *-widrig* drückt aus, dass die Eigenschaft mit negativem Vorzeichen (also schlimmer als einfach nur Null) vorliegt (nicht nur nicht gut sondern sogar schlecht) oder dass jemand aktiv am Gegenteil arbeitet.

**Nebenthema**

Übrigens finde ich den Schluß, dass *unordentlich* die Negation von *ordnungsgemäß* sei, problematisch. Das Pärchen ist offensichtlich *ordentlich/unordentlich*. Es bezieht sich primär auf die physische Anordnung von Dingen (oder auf die Charaktereigenschaft von Personen, die Dinge anordnen oder auch nicht). *Ordnungsgemäß* dagegen ist ein Wort aus einem  spezifisch bürokratisch-normativen Kontext. Dieser schwingt immer mit, wenn man das Wort verwendet. Er setzt voraus, dass es eine (geschriebene oder auch nur durch allgemeine Praxis anerkannte) formale Ordnung (Anweisung, Regelung) gibt, an die man sich halten kann oder auch nicht. Hält man sich dran, handelt man ordnungsgemäß.

Eine Schreinerwerkstatt kann ordnungsgemäß eingerichtet und doch unordentlich sein: Der Schreiner hat alle formalen Vorschriften erfüllt, aber er hat seine Werkstatt nicht aufgeräumt.

Comment: nur der Vollständigkeit halber: es gäbe da m.E. noch die Verneinung mit _un-_, wie in _unsachgemäß_. (ich überlege gerade, ob das sogar der einzige Fall ist)

Comment: @Marzipanherz  *unzeitgemäß* gibt es definitiv auch noch...  Guter Punkt. Ich füge das noch ein.

Comment: [canno.net](http://canoo.net/wordformation/gem%C3%A4%C3%9F:A) listet auch noch _unstandesgemäß_ und _unprogrammgemäß_ auf. Kannte ich aber beides vorher nicht. _standesgemäß_ hätte ich eher mit _nicht_ verneint, aber scheinbar gibt es beide Verneinungen dafür.

Comment: @Marzipanherz  Eine ganz abschließende Liste wird man nicht zusammenbringen, da bisher unübliche (oder nur ironisch verwendete) Wortgebilde auch sich einbürgern und normalisieren können. *Unstandesgemäß* klingt halbwegs vertraut für mein Ohr, ich wüsste aber nicht, wo ich das konkret schon mal getroffen haben sollte. Bei Karl May, der von der Zeit her passen würde...? Nee, der würde einfach "nicht standesgemäß" sagen. Hm... *Unprogrammgemäß* kommt mir nicht etabliert vor...

Comment: Für das Beispiel mit der Schreinerwerkstatt würde ich am liebsten ein zusätzliches upvote geben :-)

Answer (score 6):

Die systematische Art, *-gemäß* zu verneinen, ist *-widrig*. Allerdings ist *auftragswidrig* deutlich seltenener als *aftragsgerecht*, so dass *nicht auftragsgemäß* vielleicht die bessere Wahl ist.

Comment: *zeitwidrig* statt *unzeitgemäß*?